# Ransack undefined method `empty?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm trying to get a collection of feedbacks from the shop but

using ransack and search and comment_cont from feedbacks and the logs show:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `empty?' for #<Feedback:0x007f189a8fb330>)
```

someone know why like this?

Routes are:

```
resources :shops, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :show] do

post '/:id/feedbacks', to: 'shops#feedbacks', as: :search_feedbacks
post '/:id/products', to: 'shops#products', as: :search_products

#on shops controller

def feedbacks
  begin
    @shop = Shop.cached_find(params[:id])
  rescue
    @shop = nil
  end

  unless @shop.nil?    
    # @feedbacks = Feedback.by_participant(@vitrine.user, Feedback::FROM_BUYERS).paginate(:per_page => 22, :page => params[:page]).order('created_at DESC')
    @q = Feedback.by_participant(@vitrine.user, Feedback::FROM_BUYERS).ransack(params[:q])
    @feedbacks = @q.result(distinct: true).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 22)
    @average_rating_from_buyers = Feedback.average_rating(@vitrine.user, Feedback::FROM_BUYERS)
  end

end
```

Comment: May you point string where the error happens?

Comment: it's not clear where the error is coming from. since the code you share doesn't use `empty?`. Maybe you could share the error stack trace, and more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at a computer to test this but could the `distinct: true` be causing a singular result to be returned to `paginate` which may be expecting an array or a relation?

Comment: Frank, thank you. well, i will check this. so,  distinct: true is for array?
well, in this case is a association